# iText7 - how to get properties of a field date, format, export value, etc

Tags: c#, itext7

I am trying to get properties from a field on an editable form that was NOT created with iText.
I have a checkbox group (same name, call it AbcField with YES having an export value of yes and NO having an export value of no.

Yet, if I do the following:

```
if (fields.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out PdfFormField formField))
                {
                    if (formField is PdfButtonFormField)
                    {
                        var buttonField = formField as PdfButtonFormField;
                        buttonField.SetRadiosInUnison(false);
                        buttonField.SetValue(kvp.Value, true);
                    }
```

I still end up with this:
[image]

So, how do I only check ONE option?

EDIT: I found a solution, but it seems like a hack. So I was hoping for a better answer, but this does work:

```
if (formField is PdfButtonFormField)
                {
                    var buttonField = formField as PdfButtonFormField;
                    var options = fields.Where(x => x.Key.Contains($"{kvp.Key}."));

                    buttonField.SetRadiosInUnison(false);

                    if (options != null && options.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var option in options)
                        {
                            var optionField = option.Value;
                            if (optionField != null)
                            {
                                optionField.SetCheckType(PdfFormField.TYPE_CROSS);
                                var ap = optionField.GetPdfObject()?.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.AP);
                                if (ap != null)
                                {
                                    var d = ap.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.D);
                                    var n = ap.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.N);
                                    var entrySet = d != null ? d.EntrySet().Select(x => x.Key).ToList() :
                                        n?.EntrySet().Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

                                    if (entrySet != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (var entry in entrySet)
                                        {
                                            var entryText = entry.ToString();
                                            
                                            if (entryText.Equals($"/{kvp.Value}", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                            {
                                                optionField.SetValue(kvp.Value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Explicitly call SetValue for the other checkbox also? There are just 2 shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: Except that is a simple example. My form has other checkboxes with 5+ fields. And as I mentioned, they are both named the same, only the export value is different. If it were CheckYes and CheckNo, it would work, but then they wouldn't be mutually exclusive (acting like a radio button).